# Tension of block on angled surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I've got a question about a block and tension on a tilted table.  The question is as follows:

> Now the table is tilted at an angle of θ = 75° with respect to the vertical. >
>
> 3) Find the magnitude of the new acceleration of block 1.

Additionally, I'd like help with the following:

> 4) At what “critical” angle will the blocks NOT accelerate at all?

Here's the diagram I was given.

[image: Physics Image]

My understanding so far (based on help with a previous question) is that I need to derive an equation for *T* for both *m1* and *m2*.  What I've done for this is:

$$ T(m_1) = \sqrt{(m_1\sin(\theta))^2 + (m_1\cos(\theta))^2} $$

$$ T(m_2) = m_2 g - m_2 a $$

I solved for a using these two equations, but the answer I got was not correct.  Where might I be going wrong?  I image in my equation for T(*m1*), but I'm not sure how to fix it.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi again Jeff , here you cannot predict at first where the block will move. Looks like you have assumed m2 will go down. So your second eq is correct but the first one is wrong how did you got it ?